# Ajax call works on click, but not when button is submit button is pressed

Tags: ajax, django

I have the following HTML template in Django to POST a request when the user selects the select option.  The console shows the correct value based on what the user selects.  My problem is when I push the submit button my POST gets posted as None on the submitted view.  How can I get it to post on button click, i've aliased the button as my_select.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form action = "{% url 'submitted' %}" form method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
          <h2>Applications:</h3></br>

            {% for app in retreivecheckbox %}
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" checked> {{ app }}
              </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="accesslevel"><h3>Access Level</h3></label>


<select title ="accesslevelid" class="form-control my_select" id="accesslevelid">
            <option value=""> Please select your access level  </option>
            <option value="7"> Facility  </option>
            <option value="5"> Division  </option>
            <option value = "3"> Corporate  </option>
            <option value = "6"> Market  </option>
            <option value = "4"> Group  </option>
</select>

        </div>
        <div class="col">


          <label for="phi"><h3>PHI</h3></label>

          <select class="form-control my_select" id="phi" title = "phi" >
            <option value = ""> Please select if you need access to PHI data </option>
            <option value = "0"> No  </option>
            <option value = "1"> Yes  </option>

          </select>

        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
 </br> </br>

  <button href="{% url 'submitted' %}" class="btn btn-primary my_select" type = "submit"> Submit </button>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.my_select').on('click', function () {
          var phi = $('#phi').val();
          var accesslevelid = $('#accesslevelid ').val();
          $.ajax({ url: "{% url 'submitted' %}",
                  headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                  data: {
                    phi: phi,
                    accesslevelid: accesslevelid,
                  },
                  type: 'POST',
                  success: function (result) {
                    ;
                  },
                });
        });
    });
  </script>


</div>


  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your button and javascript to this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary my_select" type="submit">Submit</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var phi = $('#phi').val();
        var accesslevelid = $('#accesslevelid').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'submitted' %}",
            headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
            data: {
                phi: phi,
                accesslevelid: accesslevelid,
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                // do something with result
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

this is what i would normally use if you use Jquery 3.2.1

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        method: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function(xhr) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

also update your select elements to have

```
<select class="form-control my_select" id="phi" name="phi">
```

rather than

```
<select class="form-control my_select" id="phi" title = "phi" >
```

notice i have changed the "title" attr to "name"

Comment: I did as you suggested, i'm assuming you meant to have 'my_select' where 'form' is.   When i tried with form it just timed out on me. However, my POST results for phi and accessleveid are NULL on the submitted page using my_select.

Comment: No it should be 'form' as its listening to the submit event, what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>